# WPF cast Button RenderTransform to RotateTransform

Tags: c#, wpf

I want my button's rotation value. People were suggested like this code

```
RotateTransform rTransform = MyButton.RenderTransform as RotateTransform;
double angle = rTransform.Angle;
```

But Compiler Thorw this Exception

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in DynamicButtonP.exe.

Additional information: Unable to cast a 'System.Windows.Media.MatrixTransform' the object type 'System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform' format.
```

why I couldn't casting?

Comment: Could you please add the code where you set the `RenderTransform` property of the button? The error message suggests that the value of the property is a `MatrixTransform`, which indeed cannot be casted to `RotateTransform`.

Comment: To use WPF correctly, you should use a `DataBinding` (in xaml where you define the `RotateTransform`) to `ViewModels` property `Angle`. Here you find some information: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/wpf/2134/mvvm-in-wpf#t=201610260555030474171 about MVVM WPF

Comment: @WPFGermany It's anything but incorrect to set a UIElement's property in code behind.

Comment: @Clemens: You're right, it is not incorrect in WPF. But when you do MVVM (mostly done when using WPF) you shouldn't do this in codebehind. In this case I would prefer a `DataBinding`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the `RenderTransform` property of the Button. Its default value is [`Transform.Identity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.transform.identity(v=vs.110).aspx), which is a MatrixTransform.

Initialize the property e.g. in XAML:

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" ...>
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform/>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
</Button>
```